# PowerShell script to grab complete AD group membership of all member users for one AD group

Tags: powershell

I have an AD group with multiple users in it. I'd like to write a Powershell script to list out all the AD groups that these users are a part of.

MyADUserGroup

--> User1

--> User2

--> User3

I'd like the script to list out all the AD groups that User1, User2, and User3 are a part of. I'd also like the script to print the User's email address before listing its groups.

So far, I have:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "MyADUserGroup"
Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user' } |
Get-ADUser -Properties mail,MemberOf
```

The only issue with the script above is that the output of MemberOf is truncated since there are too many groups.

Comment: You're getting objects in return.  The console host will truncate by default.  If you want it to be readable, export it to something that's meant to be read, like CSV.  `... | Export-Csv -NoType groups.csv`